# MySQL Error TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect in docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker

Estoy inentando comunicar dos contenedores de docker ( uno con mi servidor en Nose.s/Express.js y otro de MySQL para la basede datos. El problem radica en que no puedo lograr que ambos se conecten. Pueden trabajar de forma individual pero la orden de mysql para iniciar conexion salta siempre el error. A continuacion os adjunto las configuraciones:

Error mostrado:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED localhost:3306
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js: 1054: 14))
```

Script del servidor en typescript

```
import express from 'express';
require('dotenv').config();

const app:express.Application = express();

app.use(express.json());

// database test
const mysqlInfo = require('./routes/db');

app.get("/",(
    req: express.Request, 
    res: express.Response
    ) => {
        res.send(mysqlInfo);
    });

// Routes
//app.use("/db", require("./routes/db"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`Server running at port ${port}`)
});
```

script de rutas para usuarios :

```
import express from 'express';
import mysql from 'mysql';
const router: express.Router = express.Router();


const db = require('../routes/db');
const sql_con = mysql.createConnection(db);
sql_con.connect(function(err) {
    if(err){
      console.log("Error in the connection")
      console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      console.log(`Database Connected`)
      sql_con.query(`SHOW DATABASES`, 
      function (err, result) {
        if(err)
          console.log(`Error executing the query - ${err}`)
        else
          console.log("Result: ",result) 
      })
    }
});
/*
    @route GET posts/all 
    @desc Get all posts
    @access Private
*/
router.get("/users", (req:express.Request, res:express.Response)=>res.send("users"));
router.get("/table", ()=>{
    const order = `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    Age varchar(255) 
    )`; 

module.exports = router;
```

configuracion de la base de datos:

```
require('dotenv').config();

interface SQL {
    host: string | undefined,
    user: string | undefined,
    port: string | undefined,
    password: string | undefined,
    database: string | undefined

};

//mysql
const mysqlInfo: SQL = {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST, 
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER, 
    port: process.env.MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD, 
    database:process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
}

module.exports = mysqlInfo;
```

Variables de entorno:

```
PORT=5000
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456789

MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT=3306

MYSQL_HOST=server_docker

MYSQL_USER=john
MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456789
MYSQL_DATABASE=Users_table
```

Docker y docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM node:16
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: sql_container
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE} 

    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_LOCAL_PORT}:${MYSQL_DOCKER_PORT}
    # volumes:
    #   - ./mysql/my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - users
  server:
    container_name: server_docker
    restart: always
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
        - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE} 
    networks:
      - users
networks:
    users: 
        driver: bridge
```

Llevo dias ocn este problema y no encuentro una razon para que no consigaestablecer conexion con el contenedor. Si alguien encuentra o sabe el motivo agradeceria la ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: El problema quizá es que estes usando localhost como ruta desde un contenedor, que no es lo mismo que el localhost del servidor donde se ejecuta.

Comment: En ese caso deberia asignarle localhost como host en el docker-compose?

Comment: Buenas, sigo descartando opcines y el unico momento en que el proyecto falla es cuando el servidor de Node debeconectarse al contenedor de Mysql desde su contenedor. Enel caso de inicializar el el servidor bia npm no tiene problema alguno en conectarse con el contenedor de docker de mysql.